# How to select JSON Properties as column using T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a JSON column. I want to select JSON properties as column. The property names will be unknown. So I have to use dynamic SQL. Based on this [SO suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911035/return-all-json-values-and-attributes-with-attributes-as-columns-in-sql-server-2), I was able to get properties.

```
CREATE TABLE [Templates]
(
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Template] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
)

INSERT INTO Templates(ID,Template)
VALUES (1, '{"FirName":"foo"}'),
       (2, '{"FirName":"joe","LastName":"dow"}'),
       (3, '{"LastName":"smith","Address":"1234 Test Drive"}'),
       (4, '{"City":"New York"}')

// SELECT Keys
SELECT DISTINCT(j.[key]) 
FROM Templates T
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(T.Template) AS j
```

How do I create fitting statement/WITH-clause dynamically to select properties as column? If property doesn't exist then it should return null

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30f44/12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic columns would require Dynamic SQL.  If the desired columns are known, you can use a simple pivot or even a conditional aggregation.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)= stuff((Select ','+QuoteName([key]) 
  From (SELECT DISTINCT(j.[key]) FROM Templates T
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(T.Template) AS j) A  
 Order By 1 
 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Set @SQL  = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select T.ID
              ,j.[Key]
              ,j.[Value]
         From  Templates T
         Cross Apply OpenJSON(T.Template) AS j
       ) src
Pivot ( max(value) for [Key] in ('+ @SQL+') ) pvt 
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

> **EDIT - If you don't want ID in the Final Results**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)= stuff((Select ','+QuoteName([key]) 
  From (SELECT DISTINCT(j.[key]) FROM Templates T
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(T.Template) AS j) A  
 Order By 1 
 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Set @SQL  = '
Select '+@SQL+'
 From  (
        Select T.ID
              ,j.[Key]
              ,j.[Value]
         From  Templates T
         Cross Apply OpenJSON(T.Template) AS j
       ) src
Pivot ( max(value) for [Key] in ('+ @SQL+') ) pvt 
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: as i mentioned i dont know the column names in advance

Comment: that works. However why it is necessary to include `ID` column in select? if i don't include then it only selects single row?

Comment: @LP13 If selecting a single row, no need for the ID.  Like WHERE ID=2

Comment: @LP13 To be clear, without the ID, multiple rows will compress down to one and the results would be suspect.

Comment: @LP13 See EDIT to exclude ID from the final results.  Rather than SELECT * ... we  SELECT the dynamic columns

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach is to use `OPENJSON()` with dynamically generated `WITH` clause. Note, that in this case you need to use `lax` mode in the `path` expression to guarantee that `OPENJSON()` doesn't raise an error if the object or value on the specified path can't be found.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Templates](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Template] [nvarchar](max)
)
INSERT INTO Templates(ID,Template)
VALUES
(1,'{"FirName":"foo"}'),
(2,'{"FirName":"joe","LastName":"dow"}'),
(3,'{"LastName":"smith","Address":"1234 Test Drive"}'),
(4,'{"City":"New York"}')
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''

-- Dynamic explicit schema (WITH clause)
SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
   @stm,
   N', [',
   [key],
   N'] nvarchar(max) ''lax $."',
   [key],
   '"'''
)
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT  j.[key] FROM Templates t
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(T.Template) AS j
) cte

-- Statement   
SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
   N'SELECT j.* ', 
   N'FROM Templates t ', 
   N'CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.Template) WITH (',
   STUFF(@stm, 1, 2, N''),
   N') j '
)

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------
Address         City     FirName    LastName 
--------------------------------------------
                         foo    
                         joe        dow
1234 Test Drive                     smith
                New York
```

Comment: this also works great when key names are not known